# How to add the same indentation (beginner )

Tags: indentation

How to add the same indentation to each line of a paragraphe automatically ?
Thanks

Comment: You're probably interested in *removing* the first line indentation instead of adding the same to all other lines. For that, just add `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` somewhere in your preamble.

Comment: This question isn't exactly clear. Paragraphs are indented by default in most classes. Perhaps you should spend some time with some of the resources listed here: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/11). If you're looking to remove indentation, then your question is a duplicate of [Is there an easy way to have my whole document with a space between paragraphs rather than indentation?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/42).

Comment: Can you please -- as usual here -- show us some short compilable tex code resulting in your issue?

Comment: Are you maybe interested in *hanging* indentation?

Comment: I think my question was wrong, what I have to do is write 10 seperate lines and all of them had to be indented with the same space and at the begining with a checkmark I have the checkmark and the first line is indented correctly the others or not .

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a list.

[image: list ticks]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontface\ftmark{Noto Sans Symbols2}
\newcommand\goodoh{{\large\ftmark \textcolor{blue}{}}}
\newcommand\notsogoodoh{{\large\ftmark \textcolor{red}{}}}
\begin{document}
\ldots 10 seperate lines and all of them had to be indented with the same space \ldots
\begin{itemize}
\item[\goodoh] First line
\item[\goodoh] Second line
\item[\goodoh] Third line
\item[\goodoh] Fourth line
\item[\goodoh] Fifth line
\item[\goodoh] 6th line
\item[\goodoh] Seventh line
\item[\goodoh] Eighth line
\item[\goodoh] 9th line
\item[\notsogoodoh] Tenth line
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes thank you so much, I  also did it with a hangindent{} but I don't know if it's correct